# Audio files corrected by mp3gain won't play in Audacity anymore

Tags: audio, debian, mp3, audacity

I'm using `mp3gain` to adjust the volume of several mp3 tracks (I want them to sound equally loud).

I have downloaded the [source code](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mp3gain/files/mp3gain/1.5.2/mp3gain-1_5_2_r2-src.zip/download) from the [project website](http://mp3gain.sourceforge.net/download.php), unzipped it to a folder and run `make` and `make install`, as suggested [here](https://www.linux.com/news/adjusting-mp3s-mp3gain) (there's no binaries for Debian Jessie yet). There were a few warnings during compilation, but no errors.

Then I run the command line

```
mp3gain -r -k *.mp3
```

and it seems to work fine. The music files play correctly in Gnome's Rhythmbox 3.1, VLC media player 2.2.5 and Debian Jessie's Totem Movie Player. However, in Audacity all I hear is some noise, and the length of the audio shrank from a few minutes to a few seconds (in the other software, all the music is played). Also, Audacity freezes if I press stop (but not if I let the noise play until the end).

What is going on? How can I prevent this? If I leave this as it is, is it possible (or probable) that some players won't be able to play the songs?

Below is the output of `make`.

```
cc -Wall -DHAVE_MEMCPY   -c -o mp3gain.o mp3gain.c
mp3gain.c: In function ‘changeGain’:
mp3gain.c:696:7: warning: variable ‘freqidx’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   int freqidx;
       ^
mp3gain.c: In function ‘main’:
mp3gain.c:1416:6: warning: variable ‘crcflag’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  int crcflag;
      ^
cc -Wall -DHAVE_MEMCPY   -c -o apetag.o apetag.c
apetag.c: In function ‘ReadMP3APETag’:
apetag.c:157:33: warning: variable ‘curFieldNum’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     unsigned long               curFieldNum;
                                 ^
apetag.c:146:33: warning: variable ‘flags’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     unsigned long               flags;
                                 ^
cc -Wall -DHAVE_MEMCPY   -c -o id3tag.o id3tag.c
cc -Wall -DHAVE_MEMCPY   -c -o gain_analysis.o gain_analysis.c
gain_analysis.c:119:1: warning: variably modified ‘lstepbuf’ at file scope
 Float_t          lstepbuf  [MAX_SAMPLES_PER_WINDOW + MAX_ORDER];
 ^
gain_analysis.c:121:1: warning: variably modified ‘loutbuf’ at file scope
 Float_t          loutbuf   [MAX_SAMPLES_PER_WINDOW + MAX_ORDER];
 ^
gain_analysis.c:125:1: warning: variably modified ‘rstepbuf’ at file scope
 Float_t          rstepbuf  [MAX_SAMPLES_PER_WINDOW + MAX_ORDER];
 ^
gain_analysis.c:127:1: warning: variably modified ‘routbuf’ at file scope
 Float_t          routbuf   [MAX_SAMPLES_PER_WINDOW + MAX_ORDER];
 ^
gain_analysis.c:135:1: warning: variably modified ‘A’ at file scope
 static Uint32_t  A [(size_t)(STEPS_per_dB * MAX_dB)];
 ^
gain_analysis.c:136:1: warning: variably modified ‘B’ at file scope
 static Uint32_t  B [(size_t)(STEPS_per_dB * MAX_dB)];
 ^
cc -Wall -DHAVE_MEMCPY   -c -o rg_error.o rg_error.c
cc -Wall -DHAVE_MEMCPY   -c -o mpglibDBL/common.o mpglibDBL/common.c
cc -Wall -DHAVE_MEMCPY   -c -o mpglibDBL/dct64_i386.o mpglibDBL/dct64_i386.c
cc -Wall -DHAVE_MEMCPY   -c -o mpglibDBL/decode_i386.o mpglibDBL/decode_i386.c
cc -Wall -DHAVE_MEMCPY   -c -o mpglibDBL/interface.o mpglibDBL/interface.c
cc -Wall -DHAVE_MEMCPY   -c -o mpglibDBL/layer3.o mpglibDBL/layer3.c
cc -Wall -DHAVE_MEMCPY   -c -o mpglibDBL/tabinit.o mpglibDBL/tabinit.c
cc  -o mp3gain mp3gain.o apetag.o id3tag.o gain_analysis.o rg_error.o mpglibDBL/common.o mpglibDBL/dct64_i386.o mpglibDBL/decode_i386.o mpglibDBL/interface.o mpglibDBL/layer3.o mpglibDBL/tabinit.o  -lm
```

Answer (score 0):

And all of a sudden (after I have installed `pdfshuffler`, actually), all modified files are playing perfectly on Audacity... very strange!